# How to build android version 6.4.0 with crosswalk plugin?

Tags: android, ionic2, crosswalk

I trying to build android version **6.4.0** after install crosswalk plugin version **2.4.0**.

First I removed the android platform and I reinstalled it using the following commands:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android 
ionic cordova platform add android@6.4.0
```

The installation is **succeeded**.

Moreover, I installed the crosswalk plugin using the following command line:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
```

Also the installation is **succeeded**

Now I need to build the ionic2 application!

```
ionic cordova build android
```

But the building is **failed** I got the following errors:

```
> cordova build android
    ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Khaled/Library/Android/sdk
    JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    Configuration 'compile' in project ':' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.

    null
    The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_cobuqw2y8dlztu9fe2xpnvg13.run(/Users/Khaled/iCloud Drive (Archive)/Documents/Projects/ionic/rnb/rnb-receiver/platforms/android/build.gradle:143)
    org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23+


    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:

    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    > 
    All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension. Learn more at https://d.android.com/r/tools/flavorDimensions-missing-error-message.html

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace
     option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
    --debug option to get more log output.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED
     in 1s
    (node:21899) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: /Users/Khaled/iCloud Drive (Archive)/Documents/Projects/ionic/rnb/rnb-receiver/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
    > All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension. Learn more at https://d.android.com/r/tools/flavorDimensions-missing-error-message.html

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 1s
    (node:21899) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

cordova version **8.0.0**

What is the reason for this error occurrence. and what is the solution?

Thanks.